# Non-destructively reversing an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Say I have a function:

```
function linesReverser(lines) {
  var localLines = lines.slice(); 
  localLines[1].reverse(); 
  return _.flatten(localLines);
}
```

And using it like so:

```
var input = [["Hello"],["Hello", "World"]["Attention", "Please"]];
var output1 = linesReverser(input); //["Hello", "World", "Hello", "Attention", "Please"]
var output2 = linesReverser(input); //["Hello", "Hello", "World", "Attention", "Please"]
```

Notice how the object reference is being shared. I am new to JS, but I thought copying the values would alleviate this issue (`line.slice()`), but it doesn't seem to work. Is this because of the nested arrays?

How can I non-destructively/immutably perform a reverse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're making a shallow copy of the `lines` array. To copy the nested arrays, you need to slice each one.

```
var localLines = lines.map(function(arr) {
    return arr.slice();
});
```

The `.map` method will return a new Array of the return values, which are a slice of each nested Array.

---

FWIW, here's a shorter version that will work in modern browsers, though I'd probably stick with the first one.

```
var localLines = lines.map(Array.apply.bind(Array, null));
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Wasn't far off trying this. So new to JS.

Comment: You're welcome. Since it seems you're using underscore, you may want to use its map method if you're targeting older browsers.

Comment: @JosephSilber: `Array` is just the `new Array` constructor. The `.apply` is the normal `Function.prototype.apply`. Using `.bind()`, we're binding the `this` value of `.apply()` to the `Array` function, and the first argument of `.apply()` to `null`, so the function returned will effectively do `Array.apply(null, ...)`. Since the first argument passed by `.map` is each member of the `lines` array, the call becomes `Array.apply(null, ["foo", "bar"])`, which is the same as doing `Array("foo", "bar")`, giving us a new Array with those members.

Comment: @JosephSilber: Any function that won't get tripped up by the other arguments passed by `.map()`. In reality, each call to the callback will look more like `Array.apply(null, ["foo", "bar"], 0, lines)`, where `0` is the current index, and `lines` is the original Array, but `.apply()` will ignore those extra args.

Comment: ...if you meant the first `Array`, then yes. We could  do `Function.prototype.apply` instead, or use any other function to get to `.apply()`.

Comment: @JosephSilber: You need to achieve `Array.apply(null, ["foo", "bar"])`, which is what is achieved by `Function.prototype.apply.bind(Array, null, ["foo", "bar"])()`. The way you had it, you were calling `.apply()` from the context of `Function.prototype`, which is a `function` object that does nothing. So it's like you were doing `Function.prototype(["foo","bar"])`, except giving it a `this` value of `null`. To do it your way, you would need `Function.prototype.apply.call(Array, null, ["foo", "bar"])`

Comment: ...oops, this statement: *"So it's like you were doing `Function.prototype(["foo","bar"])`..."* should read: *"So it's like you were doing `Function.prototype("foo","bar")`..."*

Comment: Why did [@JosephSilber](http://stackoverflow.com/users/825568/joseph-silber) delete all his comments???

Answer (score 27):

You can duplicate the array using ES6's spread operator, then destructively reverse the duplicate:

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const arr2 = [...arr1].reverse();
// arr1 => [1,2,3]
// arr2 => [3,2,1]
```

Comment: This deserves far more upvotes. Cleanest solution, given the insanity that `reverse()` is destructive.

Answer (score 4):

> A non-destructive approach to reverse an array in Javascript

**ES6**

```
var array = [1,2,3];
array.reduce((ary, ele) => {ary.unshift(ele); return ary}, []);
// => [3,2,1];
// array => [1,2,3];
```

**ES5**

```
array.reduce(function(obj, ele){
  obj.unshift(ele);
  return obj;
},[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can safely (deep) copy a nested array with JSON.parse and JSON.stringify, therefore the reference is not shared. Then destructively reverse the duplicate:

```
let array1 = [[1, 3], [50, 1]];
let arrayCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1));
arrayCopy.reverse(); //[[50,1],[1,3]]
```

checkout [cloning of arrays](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-clone-an-array-in-javascript-1d3183468f6a/) for more info